# Did Rabbis Moshe Feinstein and Shlomo Zalman Auerbach ever meet in person? How many times?

Tags: history, rabbis, moshe-feinstein, rav-shlomo-z-auerbach

Rav Moshe was in America, Rav Shlomo Zalman in Israel. Did they ever meet? Where and when? Do we have a photo of both of them together? (I know Rav Shlomo Zalman was asked to speak at Rav Moshe's funeral, but that wasn't my question ...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per Artscroll - new Wasserman edition "Reb Moshe" page 172 **"While Reb Moshe and Reb Shlomo Zalman never met in person"........**

The new Artscroll Reb Moshe book mentions that Reb Shlomo Zalman did not speak at his funeral.